# how can I return an array back in nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js

I called a function to count, and I would like to return the data as an array and use it then, how can I do the same
. where this returned arr is been stored, so I can use t in main code

```
var newArr =[]
    countData(jsonData).then(function (res) {
        console.log(arr)
        console.log('end')
    })

    function countData(jsonData){
        var five=0, two =0
        for(var i in jsonData){
            console.log(jsonData)
            if(jsonData.num == '5'){
                five++;
            }
            else{
                two++;
            }
        }//for
        var arr =[]
        arr[0]=five
        arr[1]=two
        return arr
    }//function
```

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `countData` *is* an array.

It isn't a Promise. The doesn't have a `then` method. Just use the return value directly.

```js
const data = {
  "num": "2",
  "num": "5",
  "num": "5",
  "num": "2",
  "num": "2",
  "num": "2"
}
const result = countData(data);
console.log(result);

function countData(jsonData) {
  var five = 0,
    two = 0
  for (var i in jsonData) {
    console.log(jsonData)
    if (jsonData.num == '5') {
      five++;
    } else {
      two++;
    }
  } //for
  var arr = []
  arr[0] = five
  arr[1] = two
  return arr
} //function
```